# How to convert NFA/DFA to java?

Tags: java, finite-automata, automata, state-machine

I have a scenario where I have designed the NFA and using JFLAP I have converted it to DFA.

I need to know, how to code it in Java?

Basically how to implement those state transitions in Java. I have seen some examples which do this using switch and if statements, but I can't see any relation to DFA/NFA design and how to use it to implement in Java.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/q/1340374/161640

Comment: @Isaac: Your link is not related to this question, this question is not about "NFA to DFA", it's about "NFA/DFA to Java"

Comment: i think @Isaac :its about converting NFA to DFA.,btw thanks

Comment: Do you want to represent *arbitrary* automata in Java or some *particular* automaton in Java? You should be able to represent automata using more-or-less the set-theoretic definition; but a particular automaton can be coded more efficiently and without the surrounding framework.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

if you want to use a more object oriented design over while(true)switch(state){...}

```
public class State{
    private Map<Character,State> transitions=new HashMap<Character,State>();

    public void addTransition(char ch,State st){
        transitions.put(ch,st);
    }

    public State next(char ch){
        return transitions.get(ch);
    }

    private boolean fin=false;
    public boolean isFinal(){return fin;}
    public boolean setFinal(boolean f){fin=f;}        


}
```

and then the loop will be

```
State currState=startState;
while(currState!=null && input.hasNextChar()){//you can also end directly when final state is reached
    char next = input.nextChar();//get next character
    currState = currState.next(next);
}

if(currState!=null && currState.isFinal()){
    // reached final state
}else{
    // to bad didn't match
}
```

Comment: I have a question can such a DFA be modeled as a kind of a directed graph ? with links between nodes containing info about characters that produce a state transition kind of like the representation of DFAS on text books how will such and idea be implemented ?

Comment: @M.K sure each node is a State object and each link is an entry in the `transitions` map

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at [`dk.brics.automaton`](http://www.brics.dk/automaton/):

> This Java package contains a DFA/NFA (finite-state automata) implementation with Unicode alphabet (UTF16) and support for the standard regular expression operations (concatenation, union, Kleene star) and a number of non-standard ones (intersection, complement, etc.)

Answer (score 0):

Although you would have implemented it by now but there is very good implementation which is easy to digest. Use Digraph to maintain the epsilon transitions and stack to keep track of expressions. Check out this link from RS [NFA.java](http://algs4.cs.princeton.edu/54regexp/NFA.java.html) .